# How to get a piece of text from a webpage and assign it to a variable using javascript/discord.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I'm trying to make a piece of code for discord bot that will display the top result from a website called giphy upon typing /gif {text}. To do this, I've already done the part where it goes to the respective link (the search results). Now I want to extract the a-href (link) from the first result (the one which opens when you click it) and assign it to a variable, which I can display upon request. Also, I don't want to send a URL but an attachment using the `{files: []} part` of `.send`

I don't have any idea where to begin to extract from some other webpage using discord.js
I've also thought of adding a `view-source:` but I don't know how to extract a piece of text and assign to a variable
There's a way in HTML (JavaSript DOM?) but it uses i-frames.

```
else if (message.content.search("/gif") == 0) {
    let msg = message.content;
    let gif1 = msg.split("/gif")[1].trim()
    let gif2 = gif1.replace(" ", "-");
    let gif = "https://giphy.com/search/" + gif2;
      message.channel.send("Most relevant result for" + " " + gif1, {files: [gif]} )
      }
```

Apparently, the above code displays a text file in the discord channel. I want it to display the gif that is the first result, without displaying the link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend using [`giphy-api`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/giphy-api):
With it you can do:

```
var giphyApi = require("giphy-api")();
giphyApi.search({
    q: 'pokemon',
    rating: 'g'
}, function (err, res) {
    console.log(res.data[0].images.original.url)
});
```

And it will console.log: `https://media3.giphy.com/media/iBANmdIlMNJVC/giphy-preview.gif?cid=e1bb72ff5ca0b1d72f66564d45c6925c`

Wich means you can do:

```
var giphyApi = require("giphy-api")();

giphyApi.search({
    q: 'pokemon',
    rating: 'g'
}, function (err, res) {
    message.channel.send('Gif:', new Discord.Attachment(res.data[0].images.original.url , 'gif.gif'))
});
```

Comment: I'm trying to use their giphy.random() function, but it's not working with this code, it says `cannot read property "images" of undefined`. Is res.data[0] undefined here? Could you help me please? @PLASMA chicken

Comment: For random its `res.data.images.original.url`

Comment: why doesn't the website show all the correct commands? :( I saw giphy.random there

Comment: Ah, so not using the index basically gives random there, I didn't read properly.

Answer (score 0):

```
    client.on('message', async message => {
    if(message.content.includes("!gif")){
const args = message.content.slice().trim().split(/ +/g);
const command = args.shift().toLowerCase(); 
let converts = args.join(" ");  

if(converts ==""){converts = "random"}  
 giphyApi.search({
    q: converts,
    rating: 'g'
}, function (err, res) {
let embed = new Discord.RichEmbed()
.setColor(0x00ae86)
.setTitle(` Result for ${converts}`)
.setImage((res.data[0].images.original.url))
message.channel.send({embed:embed})  

}); 
}

});
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value. It should also be formatted properly to allow easier reading.